# Restlet Java SE 2.1.2 jvm memory usage

Tags: restlet

we use Restlet to make many concurrent http requests to a web server. A couple of days ago we upgrade Restlet libs from 2.0.14 to 2.1.2 and we note a very high heap memory consumption with respect to the old version. 
Here are some data:
- 2.0.14 -> 100 threads ~115MB
- 2.1.2 -> 30 threads ~90MB

Has anyone else notice this behaviour?

Here is an example of a request:

```
...
clientResource = new ClientResource(URI);
representation = clientResource.get(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
...
```

Thx

Comment: Which HTTP client connector are you using? The default/internal one?

Comment: Yes, the default one!
Another error we are getting on Debian 6.0.5 is:
"Unable to open a controller's NIO selector. IOException: to many open files."
I see that a similar problem as already been fixed ([Issue 1200][1]).
Is It something related to the above problem?


  [1]: http://restlet.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4375&viewType=browseAll&dsMessageId=2715214

Comment: You should add org.restlet.ext.net.jar (or org.restlet.ext.httpclient.jar) to your classpath to replace the default connector by a more scalable/stable one.

Comment: I'm sorry. Old Restlet version was 2.0.3.

Comment: Many thanks Jerome I'll try it and I let you know.

Comment: Now the memory is being released, thanks :)